# How to incorporate boundary conditions into a finite element iterative solver without plugging them in directly?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, boundary-value-problem, finite-element-method

I'm looking for papers on solving finite element problems without plugging in the boundary values directly, but I'm not having great luck.

Specifically, I want to leave the boundary values of my finite element system as unknowns (say the interior values are $x_0$ and the boundary values are $x_1$) and then form the linear system

$$ \left[\matrix{A_0 \\ A_1}\right]\left[\matrix{x_0 \\ x_1}\right] = \left[\matrix{f_0 \\ f_1}\right]$$

where $f_0$ and $f_1$ are known, and then when I use a linear system solver (jacobi, GS, CG, etc), I'd like to impose the boundary conditions as part of the iteration.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I think that this will be advantageous since it will preserve some of the symmetry from the structure of the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write the system as

$$\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\0&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_{interior}\\x_{boundary}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f\\0\end{pmatrix},$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something a little more complicated than this. Would it be possible to modify the bottom row without knowing the solution to $x_{interior}$ to make it look like $B x_{interior} + C x_{boundary} = g$?

Comment: @GrahamHarper I guess you want to have a symmetric matrix in the end?

Comment: A symmetric matrix or an SPD matrix would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Nitsche's method](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-267/S0025-5718-08-02183-2/S0025-5718-08-02183-2.pdf)? This results in a SPD matrix.